# Azure Authentication Microsoft Graph

Tags: android, azure, kotlin, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using azure authentication for android app. Everything is working fine. Followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android I just want to ask, Is there any possibility we can set height for this webView or add any view over the webView? I just have requirement to complete using one of these.

Config File:

```
 {
   "client_id": "client_id",
   "authorization_user_agent": "WEBVIEW",
   "redirect_uri": "redirect_url",
   "account_mode": "SINGLE",
   "authorities": [
    {
      "type": "AAD",
      "audience": {
       "type": "AzureADMyOrg",
       "tenant_id": "my_tenant_id"
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

thanks,

Comment: Hi @Saad, Which page in the code you are trying to set height? Please share how you are implementing?

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity I wanted to set height for the webView which appears to ask for the credentials or have own custom web-view. i have searched out, Microsoft doesn't allow these kind of customisation for security purpose.

Comment: Hi @saad, please check my answer and let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since, this page is generated by the MSAL/ADAL plugin I believe It
   cannot be achieved.
2. The changes we can implement to Azure AD login page are limited to
   [adding Branding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding) and it is not possible to configure dark mode
   for MSAL/ADAL web views as this page is generated by the MSAL/ADAL
   plugin.